# C++ Pointer Math

Tags: c++, math, pointers

Got a question about C++ Pointer addition.  If you look at the screen shot provided you can basically see I'm doing a memcpy(m_pBuf + m_iWritePtr .... and this memory pointer addition is not working as expected.

I had thought that the addition of m_pBuf + m_iWritePtr would add m_iWritePtr bytes to my memory address m_pBuf.  m_pBuf is a pointer to a structure array; i.e. (T *)m_pBuf = new T[cnt] where T is a typename and cnt is the number of T objects allocated.  T is, in this case a simple structure.  The sizeof(T) in this case is 260.

The memcpy call is throwing a fault and I know my pointer math is wrong but I'm not 100% sure why.  The memcpy is coded to, I thought, to take the base address and add some n * 260 bytes to get an offset into the buffer.  NOTE:  This code use to work when this was not a template implementation and T was simply a char *.  Now that T is a template of some typename, the offset addition no longer works as expected.

So if you look at the screen shot below, here are the results of various calculations/references I did using the compiler's debugger/inspector and a calculator:

```
The memory address of m_pBuf     = 0x01E7E0E0

The memory address of m_pBuf[1]  = 0x01E8EE04
the memory address of m_pBuf+1     = 0x01E8EE04
the memory address of m_pBuf++     = 0x01E8EBFC  
the memory address of m_pBuf+260   = 0x01E7E1E4 (the calculator's result)
```

I'm trying to understand what's going on here.  The first two seem correct but I don't understand why none of these are equal.  This is 32bit compiler on Windows 7-64bit.

[image]

To further explain, this is a ring buffer of type T with a size of n * T objects of storage.  Here is the code:

```
template<typename T>
bool TMsgBuffer<T>::PutMsgEx(T *pBuf, unsigned long nObjCount )
{
 bool bResult = false;
 unsigned long MaxWriteSize, nPutLen;

 Lock();

 MaxWriteSize = GetMaxWriteSize();  // this returns size of my buffer in total.
 nPutLen = nObjCount * m_nObjSize;  // m_nObjSize is set else where to sizeof(T)


 if(nPutLen <= MaxWriteSize)
 {
     // easy case, no wrapping
     if( m_iWritePtr + nPutLen <= m_nBufSize )
     {
         memcpy(m_pBuf + m_iWritePtr, pBuf, nPutLen);
         m_iWritePtr += nPutLen;
     }
     else // need to wrap
     {
         m_iFirstChunkSize = m_nBufSize - m_iWritePtr;
         m_iSecondChunkSize = nPutLen - m_iFirstChunkSize;

         memcpy(m_pBuf + m_iWritePtr, pBuf, m_iFirstChunkSize );
         memcpy(m_pBuf, pBuf + m_iFirstChunkSize, m_iSecondChunkSize );

         m_iWritePtr = m_iSecondChunkSize;
     }

     //m_MsgCount++;
     m_MsgCount+= nObjCount;
     bResult = true;
 }

 Unlock();

 return bResult;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful about the order of the operations.  I am guessing you did the ++ first:

```
m_pBuf++     = 0x01E8EBFC
```

The effect of the postincrement is to **change the value but print out the old value**, so if you printed m_pBuf i am guessing you would get 0x1E8ED00.

If you then ran

```
m_pBuf+1     = 0x01E8EE04
```

the new value is correct (the difference is sizeof(T) = 260)

Show the neighboring code, and be sure that you are careful regarding statements with side effects.

Comment: no, the m_pBuf++ is not in code.  It was put into my IDE's debugger to evaluate the result of 'm_pBuf++' as well as 'm_pBuf+1'.  What is going on code-wise is this is a ring buffer of size N of T objects.  I put data into the ring buffer with one thread and take it out in another thread.  The code above is the portion where I am attempting to put data into the buffer.  I do some work to see where I am in the buffer (m_iWritePtr) and then use memcpy to store the object at the appropriate m_iWritePtr offset.

Comment: 0x01E8EE04 - 0x01E7E0E0 does not equal 260.  I'm getting 68,900.

Comment: 0x01E8EBFC-0x01E8EE04 equals 260.  Is m_iWritePtr the actual write pointer?  If so why wouldnt you just memcpy at that address? (you probably want to add the **offset**, not the address

Comment: " i am guessing you would get 0x1E8ED00"  I'm arguing this is not so.  In the screen shot to the left, the debugger is show that the address is 0x01E7E0E0 or is 0x01E7E0E0 the memory address of my variable instead?  I guess if you are correct, then my error is that I am misinterpreting what my debugger is showing me.  This is C++ Builder Rad XE

Comment: the statement x++, when x is of type T*, returns x but shifts the address for x by sizeof(T) bytes.  Its not clear from a static screen shot which statement was evaluated first.  I'm also not fully sure of the order in which your IDE / debugger would actually evaluate the results.  Is there an immediate window [akin to the VS immediate window] or a console [like with GDB]?

Comment: ultimately it was your help that led me to through this.  It's a little embarrassing to say but I was pretty sure m_pBuff++ was incrementing the pointer by the sizeof(T) but when the app was throwing faults, I had changed to what you see in my post.  Then I misinterpreted my IDE's debugger output.  So I began questioning years of knowledge, hmmm, anyway, thanks for the help!  This web site rocks!

Comment: just to clarify:  In my original post I said "The memory address of m_pBuf = 0x01E7E0E0" is technically true.  My thought process was that this was the content of the pointer.  As it turns out it's the pointer's address itself.

Comment: @Eric tis ok -- we are but mere mortals

Answer (score 2):

Pointer math works in a logical manner.  When you add `n` to a pointer of type `Foo` it advances the pointer `sizeof(Foo) * n` bytes, not `n` bytes.  Anyway, why would you add the one pointer to another anyway?  What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: This was my understanding, but the numbers are not adding up.  m_pBuf+1 = 0x01E8EE04 which does not equal 0x01E7E1E4 (calculator result is showing result of 0x01E7E0E0 + 260)

Answer (score 2):

As Ed and Martin said, pointer math involves the size of the type for the pointer.

Adding one to a pointer increases the address of the pointer by the size of the type.

Now one thing you don't mention is the type of `m_pBuf`.

But from your debugging session, the compiler/debugger believes that `(char *)&m_pBuf[1]  - (char *)m_pBuf == 0x01E8EE04 - 0x01E7E0E0 == 0x10D24 == 68900 decimal

68900 / 260 (sizeof T) == 265

So the compiler/debugger believes that m_pBuf is T[265].

But as Foo Bah noted, the `m_pBuf++` modified the pointer. So the two debugger view expressions `m_pBuf[[1]]` and `m_pBuf+1` probably occurred after `m_pBuf++` since the window for `m_pBuff++` shows a smaller value than the other two test expressions.

Readjusting for that scenario, we end up with m_pBuf is T[263].

If you wanted to access the first T bytes from the beginning of m_pBuf, you can cast `m_pBuf` to `(char *)` before doing the pointer arithmetic. There are most likely more elegant solutions, but you haven't shown enough code yet - those darn debugger expression windows are covering up important stuff!

Answer (score 1):

It might help to post the code.

Remember incrementing a pointer of type T increases it by sizeof(T) bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess: `m_pBuf` isn't a pointer to `T*` but a pointer to `T[265]`, right? That's the only way that `m_pBuf+1` could equal the address of `(char*)m_pBuf + 260*265`.